# How to assign ratio values to two different variables?

Tags: magento2

```
$productRatio = $_productCollection->getRatio();
```

I got 3:1 , How to assign this to two different variables. 3 should be assigned to $resin and 1 should be assigned to $hardner.
I tried this but am getting error.

```
$resin:$hardner :: $productRatio ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set your value using below way,

```
$newValue = explode(":",$productRatio);
$resin = $newValue[0];
$hardner = $newValue[1];
echo $resin.':'.$hardner;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rakesh. Its Working fine.I was trying since yesterday.thanks once again.

Comment: @Dilip Glad to know you have helpful